# Unexpected ReSharper warning with RelativeSource binding in Xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In the following snippet of code, I get a warning from ReShaper

"Cannot resolve property 'MyCommand' in data context of type 'object'"

I have the following questions

- Is this the correct way when I want to execute a command from the viewmodel with a parameter from the the ItemSource
- Why do I get this warning?
- How can I get rid of this warning?
- If not, can I safely ignore the warning

So the code works as expected, but I'm worried about the warning

This is not my code but I extracted a simplified snippet for simplification in order to reproduce the problem

This is my code

xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:app1="clr-namespace:App1;assembly=App1"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <app1:MainViewModel></app1:MainViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Template">
            <Button Text="{Binding}" 
                    Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.MyCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type CollectionView}} }" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}">
            </Button>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <StackLayout>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Template}">

        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

viewmodel

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App1
{
    public class MainViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }= new ObservableCollection<string>() {"1", "2", "3"} ;

        public Command<string> MyCommand { get; set; }

    }
}
```

xaml.cs

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App1
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainViewModel.MyCommand = new Command<string>(ShowMessage);
        }

        private MainViewModel MainViewModel => (MainViewModel)BindingContext;


        private void ShowMessage(string message)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Information", message, "OK");
        }

    }
}
```

I try to do the binding in a different way but then the code did not work anymore
For example, I changed Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type CollectionView}} into Source={x:Reference MyPage but I still got the warning

Comment: You need to add x:DataType properties to your XAML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix that by setting up compiled bindings properly. Like Jason already suggested, you should use the `x:DataType` attribute for this on both the *ContentPage* root and on the *DataTemplate*.

However, you also need to set up the binding a little bit differently. Instead of binding to the `BindingContext` and the `CollectionView` as the source, you should directly bind to the ViewModel:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:app1="clr-namespace:App1;assembly=App1"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage"
             x:DataType="app1:MainViewModel">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <app1:MainViewModel></app1:MainViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Template"
                      x:DataType="{x:Type System:String}">
            <Button Text="{Binding}" 
                    Command="{Binding MyCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type app1:MainViewModel}} }" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}">
            </Button>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <StackLayout>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Template}">

        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Thanks Julian. This fixed the warning. And I also learned something about Xamarin and Xaml

Answer (score 0):

the XAML compiler doesn't know what types you are binding to, so it can't precompile.  You can solve this by using the [DataType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings) parameter

add one to your page to set the VM type

```
<ContentPage ...
 x:DataType="app1:MainViewModel"
 ... >
```

and another to your `DataTemplate` so it knows the type it is bound to

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template"
 x:DataType="{x:Type System:String}" >
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not fix the error. Still get the same warning with ReSharper

Comment: you can ignore it